# Memory leak in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, extjs5

I have an ExtJS Sencha application that seems to have a client-side memory leak.

The only thing I don't know is how to take care of the stores.  I've put *autoDestroy: true* on both of the stores I use - but I still get the leak.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normally, ExtJS should do the cleanup for you. BUT, as per ExtJS6 docs, [a memory leak can be caused by `keepRawData:true`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-cfg-keepRawData). I guess that this also holds for ExtJS5, where `keepRawData:true` **is the default setting**. You may want to try again with `keepRawData:false` on your stores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your stores are derived then you need to call base class clean up from your derived onDestroy()function otherwise it may get by-passed.Please refer [extjs guidelines](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/core_concepts/memory_management.html) for memory leaks.
[image]

Comment: Thank you.  Just one other thing - is callParent() something you call on the store itself - or the parent?  So far I haven't been able to get that to work.  Thanks!